# Which one to use - Kml or Google Map Api 

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, google-maps-api-2

I want to show locations on google map based on the user search criteria i.e; if a user selects London, then all records from London should be displayed  and if user enters his postcode then it should show the result within 25 miles of his postcode on the google map(All data will be coming from database php/mysql).

Now the question is What should I use? KML or google map api V3, As i want to give option to user to see brief info about the location, when he will mousehover that marker, and onClick of that marker I want to show the image of location and review count, and distance(calculated dynamically based on his postcode.), I also want to ceate custom markers. I have done some work on api V3 previously but wanted to know about KML. Does it supports my need? As according to my understanding KML is just a static file and can't give such dynamics.If so, can you please provide any sample and how to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct, KML are just static files. You should be able to complete your requirements using combination of google maps api v3 methods like geocode, computeDistance etc.

Comment: So, in what scanario we use KML then as it is good for SEO. Is there any way i could achieve through KML? like generating KML through php/mysql then parsing that kml for google map api..really confused

Comment: It is possible to locate a position in a region specified by KML data. I'd prepare a polygon using the KML and they use relevant methods to find locations in the region - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly

Comment: need some productive and detail answer..help